# Value of variable of the if statement is correct but in output I see value of else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

Value of variable of the if statement is correct but in output I see value of else statement
Why its not printing "hi me"

```
>>> name = input("Whats your name: ")
Whats your name: "john"
>>> if name == "john":
...     print("hi me")
... elif name == "jesus":
...     print("hi you")
... else:
...     print("hi stranger")
...
hi stranger
```

Comment: Are you putting the input in with quotes? (dont)

Comment: @Sayse Yes, It looks like OP has inputted ```"john"``` instead of ```john```

Answer (score 0):

Either yust write `john` instead of `"john"` as input or change your comparison from `"john"` to `'"john"'` depending what you need.

Comment: @Md Jewele Islam
Thanks dear

Answer (score 0):

Quotes are used as part of Python's syntax to mark string literals. They are (in your case at least) not part of the content of the string. If you print out the value of a string you will see that:

```py
print("john")
```

gives just `john`, whereas if you enter your name with quotes:

```py
>>> name = input("Whats your name: ")
Whats your name: "john"
>>> print(name)
```

it will output `"john"` because now the quotes are actually part of the string. That is however different from `john` without quotes which is why your `if` statement doesn't work as you expect.

The solution, as pointed out in the comments already, is to enter your name without quotes.

Comment: I tested this but it gives me this error




    >>> name = input("Whats your name: ")
    Whats your name: john
    >>> if name == john:
    ...     print("hi me")
    ... elif name == jesus:
    ...     print("hi you")
    ... else:
    ...     print("hi stranger")
    ...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'john' is not defined

Comment: You still have to use quotes in your `if` statement because that is what Python's syntax requires. My point is that there are different rules for your code and your data.

Comment: The `NameError` is because you are using Python 2. You can fix it by using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. But as a beginner you *really should not* be investing time learning Python 2.

Comment: @BoarGules the NameError comes from the unknown symbol `john` because OP didn't surround it with quotes. Nothing to do with Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

as NoahResch answered your issued is from your input. So another Idea is to use `upper()`. Try this:

```
>>> name = input("Whats your name: ")
Whats your name: "john"
>>> name = name.upper()
>>> if name == "JOHN":
...     print("hi me")
... elif name == "JESUS":
...     print("hi you")
... else:
...     print("hi stranger")
...
hi me
```

also don't put quotation mark on the input `John`

Comment: How does that change anything about the result?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are trying to input `"john"` It is executing as a `str` So it looks like `'"john"'`. So If you want to remove `"` from `"john"`

```
name = input("Whats your name: ")
Whats your name: "john"
name = name.replace('"', '')
if name == "john":
     print("hi me")
 elif name == "jesus":
     print("hi you")
 else:
     print("hi stranger")
hi me
```

or if you really check `"john"`

```
name = input("Whats your name: ")
Whats your name: "john"
if name == '"john"':
     print("hi me")
 elif name == '"jesus"':
     print("hi you")
 else:
     print("hi stranger")
hi me
```